# Context.consumer not rendering the content. ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My UserContext.Consumer is not rendering the variables, only the elements,

First Name: for example. I am trying to feed this component with the contents of the data but not map it, this is an individual user page even though in the terminal it loads all items stored in mongodb.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import '../App.css'
import UserContext from '../contexts/UserContext';

function User() {
    let users = useContext(UserContext);

    return (
        <UserContext.Consumer>
            {
                ({ users }) => {
                    return <div>
                        <div>

                            <div className='users_list' key={users.username}>
                                <h1>User Profile: {users.username}</h1>
                                <p>First Name: {users.firstName}</p>
                                <p>Last Name: {users.lastName}</p>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </UserContext.Consumer>
    );
}


export default User;
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the useContext hook then you can do:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import '../App.css'
import UserContext from '../contexts/UserContext';

function User() {
    let users = useContext(UserContext);

    return  <div>
                <div>
                   <div className='users_list' key={users.username}>
                           <h1>User Profile: {users.username}</h1>
                            <p>First Name: {users.firstName}</p>
                             <p>Last Name: {users.lastName}</p>
                           </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
}

export default User;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply!! I replaced the code but still does not show the user information. In the console I get this error "AxiosError {message: 'Unsupported protocol mongodb:', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}}
code
: 
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
message
: 
"Unsupported protocol mongodb:"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error"

Comment: any ideas what that could be? Thanks again